# Qt: Background video in QtWebKit

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

While HTML5 media tags aren't working in QtWebKit 2.2.2 and it's a known issue, but I still need to get this demo done on time. I need the media tags to display a video behind some HTML, which I don't mind doing without the media tags if its possible. I'm running Windows XP using MinGW. I was able to compile the latest webkit. I'm trying to integreate QtMultimedia from the QtMoblity package as some said it fixes the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've just write a code with QT version 4.8, nothing went wrong. Did you provide the media plugin to play the video? There is a nice example in [this](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/WebRender?content=140450) link, you can look at its source code, you don't have to include phonon or mobility for such a job.